# OpenID Connect, OAuth2 and User Details Syncronization

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, openid

I have created a OpenID Connect / Authorization server based in large part on IdentityServer V3 from Thinktecture. For the sake of simplicity assume that this entire platform consists of the following:

- An ASP.NET Web API hosting IdentityServer v3 and exposing controllers to manage the ASP.NET Identity implementation that Idv3 is using for OpenID Connect. We will call this the AuthServer.
- Two additional resource servers, also ASP.NET web API, we can call them API1 and API2.
- Total of 3 AngularJS based implicit clients, one each to work with the API's (AuthServer management front end, API1 front end and API2 front end).

There are several other clients out there (mobile apps, etc...) but they are not pertinent to the question.

When a new user attempts to register on the platform, either from the front end of API1 or API2, they are walked through a wizard on the Angular front end and during the process a user is created through the AuthServer API (ASP.NET Identity). At this point in time the user is authenticated through AuthServer and they have both a token and id_token and can successfully use the services through the front end for which ever API they registered for.

The difficulty I have having is two fold:

1. Where would you generally store user details? The AuthServer needs at the very least an email address (email address validation and lost password) as well as a first name and last name to make communications more personal. The API in question (API1 or API2) require various details about the user (address, date of birth, etc...) and due to this variability it does not make sense to store them in the identity server. I am leaning towards storing the initially registered values for First, Last and Email in both places and then only allow updates in the front end for the apps (API1 and API2) and make those apps responsible for updating the AuthServer via a client credential flow. Does this make the most sense?
2. I am using UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication which is a wrapper for UseOAuthBearerAuthentication in my OWIN pipeline. I am able to successfully authorize the user, validate my claims, etc... However I am having difficulty determining how to get the issuing authority out of the context successfully and determining where the correct place is in the pipeline to call the userinfo end point in order to retrieve user details from the AuthServer. I can do it at the controller level, injecting a user details service into it but I would really like to do this at a higher level and append the details to the users identity so that if the app requires some specific details about the user each and every time it is called, the API can call the AuthServer to retrieve them. This is very straight forward in the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication MVC implementation as they have eventing that allows for direct access to the authentication ticket. Is there a "correct" way to do this?